# Replace {{something}} in multiple strings with variables

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to replace all these strings:

```
'Apples are {{appleColor}}'
'Oranges are {{orangeColor}}'
'My name is {{name}}'
```

With these:

```
obj = {
  appleColor: 'red',
  orangeColor: 'orange',
  name: 'Todd'
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can do this is most browsers today with template strings in plain JS using `${}`

Comment: You're trying to? So what have you tried? OR do you mean you want to?

Comment: mustache.js does this exact thing and more

Answer (score 8):

Simple solution using **[String.prototype.replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)** function with *replacement callback*:

```js
var str = "'Apples are {{appleColor}}', 'Oranges are {{orangeColor}}', 'My name is {{name}}' ",
    obj = {
        appleColor: 'red',
        orangeColor: 'orange',
        name: 'Todd'
    };

str = str.replace(/{{(\w+)}}/g, function (m, m1) {
  return obj[m1] || m;  
});

console.log(str);
```

Comment: there are a few caveats worth mentioning with this approach; error handling reveals data names, "toString" et al conflicts, nest snafu, only wordy key names (no `_` or `$` support), no object path depth, etc.

Comment: @dandavis, As I wrote *Simple solution* ... for simple cases )